# Logistic Regression | Exercise

Tags: probability, statistics, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I am trying to solve questions 2 to 7 of this exercise [exercise sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9D9sG.png)

At the moment, I don't know how to answer these questions.

But I have some ideas for the second question :

- Do I have to study this application ?

\begin{align*}
   R^{d} &\to R^{d}\\
  y &\mapsto H_{n}(y)^{-1}\nabla ln(\beta^{*}).
\end{align*}

- A friend pointed out to me that question 2 may refer to Newton's method. That is to say that a step of Newton's method makes it possible to approach the solution. What do you think ?

Comment: Please try to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting instead of pictures.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where does the exercise sheet come from? I like it. Are there more exercise sheets like this one?

Comment: Done ! :) @StubbornAtom

Comment: Of course! @littleO There are also similar worksheets on other topics (SVM, Adaboost, Kernels and RKHS ..) : https://stephanegaiffas.github.io/teaching/m2mo . 
It is an introductory course in ML organized by Mr. S. Gaïffas at the University of Paris